# OData V4 boolean unexpectedly converted to 'No' / 'Yes' strings for ODatamodel V4 binding

Tags: sapui5

From testing it turns out the boolean returned by the OData V4 service was translated to strings 'No' and 'Yes' somewhere between the READ and the binding. I have no idea what can be causing this.

OData loaded by $batch request to load suggestion items:

```js
{
  "@odata.context": "$metadata#SkillVocabularyItems",
  "value": [
    {
      "randomId": "622d4068-9928-4446-931a-45b443356dae",
      "skill": "MongoDB",
      "trending": true
    },
    {
      "randomId": "d9ed304a-c1bc-454c-b4db-970f87ee3943",
      "skill": "MongoLab",
      "trending": false
    }
]
}
```

XML binding that I expect to work

```xml
          <SearchField
            id="searchField"
            busy="{view>/loadingSkillSuggestions}"
            placeholder="Search for a skill..."
            enableSuggestions="true"
            suggest=".onSuggestSkills"
            suggestionItems="{/SkillVocabularyItems}"
          >
            <suggestionItems>
              <SuggestionItem
                icon="{= ${trending}? 'sap-icon://trend-up' : '' }"
                text="{skill}"
                description="{trending}"
                key="{skill}"
              />
            </suggestionItems>
          </SearchField>
```

XML binding that works, showing the value in the model is litterally 'No' or 'Yes'. This 'No' or 'Yes' is also visible in the 'description' of the SuggestionItems.

---

```xml
          <SearchField
            id="searchField"
            busy="{view>/loadingSkillSuggestions}"
            placeholder="Search for a skill..."
            enableSuggestions="true"
            suggest=".onSuggestSkills"
            suggestionItems="{/SkillVocabularyItems}"
          >
            <suggestionItems>
              <SuggestionItem
                icon="{= ${trending}? 'sap-icon://trend-up' : '' }"
                text="{skill}"
                description="{trending}"
                key="{skill}"
              />
            </suggestionItems>
          </SearchField>
```

Comment: It's automatic, and display only. Value itself is still boolean. It's done I guess because "true" and "false" are less user friendly, not to mention, also strings technically. What is your actual question?

Comment: If the value itself is a boolean, then I should be able to use the value in the expression binding comparison.

Answer (score 4):

Found the documentation where this behavior is described.

> By default, a property binding delivers a value formatted according to the target type of the control property it applies to...

Source: [Type Determination](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/53cdd55a77ce4f33a14bd0767a293063)

The solution is to use `%` for the binding expression instead of `$`:

> The embedded binding `${binding}` delivers a value formatted according to the target type of the control property the expression binding applies to, for example, "boolean" in case of `<Icon src="sap-icon://message-warning" visible="{= ${status} === 'critical' }">`. This can be undesirable or even lead to errors, for example, if OData V4 automatically adds the correct type for the "status" property which is string-like, not boolean. In such cases, use the syntax `%{binding}` instead.

Source: [Expression Binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0)